# Programming a reset button?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm currently making a mortgage calculator, but I need some help. I have a reset button on my GUI that makes all of the forms blank again after typing something into them. The IDE already helped me make the button, so here is where I'm at:

```
private void resetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

What do I need to put in here?

Comment: Can you reference all of the form fields? If so, how do you think you should approach it?

Comment: Probably your code to reset the form. Note This is not a site to write code for you, include what you have tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either recreate your complete GUI (probably not an option), or painstakingly use `.setText("")` against each and every input field you have, and similar logic for radio buttons, etc. There's no royal way to it, unfortunately.